# javascript Convert String to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, string

Using javascript how can convert a String

```js
let string = '{lat:41.66787,lng:25.54585,color:0,title:My_Title,snippet:My_Snippet,draggable:false}'
```

to JSON like

```js
let json = {"lat":41.66787,"lng":25.54585,"color":0,"title":"My_title","snippet":"My_Snippet","dragabple":false}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `JSON.stringify(object);`

Comment: @hurricane I don't see how `JSON.stringify` (or `JSON.parse`) could help here. The string isn't valid JSON.

Comment: `let json = {"lat":41.66787,"lng":25.54585,"color":0,"title":"My_title","snippet":"My_Snippet","dragabple":false}
` isn't JSON. It's a JavaScript object literal. You should read: [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation). There is no JSON in your question.

Comment: @Spectric The duplicate won't help here. The string isn't JSON.

Comment: @jabaa question has been changed after my comment :)

Comment: @hurricane Now, I get it. Yes, your comment made sense for the initial question.

Comment: sorry, I'm a beginner
and I may not have explained the problem correctly
What I want is to convert this string object to JSON format so that I can then get the .obj
such as obj.lat and obj.lng